# Server admin limit exceeded (AzureAD add password/client secret)

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

When creating a new password/client secret for an app registration using Terraform I get the following error. Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9951032Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.248Z [INFO] provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.36.0_x5: 2023/05/05 10:06:24 [DEBUG] ============================ Begin AzureAD Request ============================
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9951240Z Request ID: 1a383e68-291a-f30e-af0b-ba66f5352ce7
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9951250Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9951535Z POST /beta/applications/<removed>/addPassword HTTP/1.1
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9951644Z Host: graph.microsoft.com
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9952169Z User-Agent: HashiCorp Terraform/1.4.6 (+https://www.terraform.io) Terraform Plugin SDK/2.10.1 terraform-provider-azuread/dev Hamilton (Go-http-client/1.1) pid-222c6c49-1b0a-5959-a213-6608f9eb8820
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9952297Z Content-Length: 111
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9952529Z Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8; IEEE754Compatible=false
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9952720Z Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9952850Z Odata-Maxversion: 4.0
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9952972Z Odata-Version: 4.0
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9953100Z Accept-Encoding: gzip
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9953107Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9953465Z {“passwordCredential”:{“displayName”:“Client secret ”}}
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9953740Z ============================= End AzureAD Request =============================: timestamp=2023-05-05T10:06:24.248Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9954246Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.430Z [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.52.0_x5: Generated Provider Correlation Request Id: b701e369-4abf-2ad0-a7c3-8a42d0043207: timestamp=2023-05-05T10:06:24.428Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9955799Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] maybeTainted: module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password encountered an error during creation, so it is now marked as tainted
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9956357Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState to workingState for module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9956927Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState: removing state object for module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9957403Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] evalApplyProvisioners: module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password is tainted, so skipping provisioning
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9957857Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] maybeTainted: module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password was already tainted, so nothing to do
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9958490Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState to workingState for module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9959085Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z [TRACE] NodeAbstractResouceInstance.writeResourceInstanceState: removing state object for module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9959689Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.586Z [ERROR] vertex “module.environment.module..azuread_application_password.app_registration_password” error: Adding password for application with object ID “<removed>”
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9960120Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.586Z [TRACE] vertex “module.environment.module.<removed>.azuread_application_password.app_registration_password”: visit complete, with errors
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9960608Z 2023-05-05T10:06:24.586Z [INFO] provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.36.0_x5: 2023/05/05 10:06:24 [DEBUG] ============================ Begin AzureAD Response ===========================
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9960958Z POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<removed>/addPassword
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961160Z Request ID: 1a383e68-291a-f30e-af0b-ba66f5352ce7
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961167Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961261Z HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961400Z Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961523Z Cache-Control: no-cache
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961745Z Client-Request-Id: 8e624ae8-710f-49e8-a15b-7050cb9b0e42
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961896Z Content-Type: application/json
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9961997Z Date: Fri, 05 May 2023 10:06:24 GMT
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9962187Z Request-Id: 8e624ae8-710f-49e8-a15b-7050cb9b0e42
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9962370Z Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9962497Z Vary: Accept-Encoding
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9962871Z X-Ms-Ags-Diagnostic: {“ServerInfo”:{“DataCenter”:“Central US”,“Slice”:“E”,“Ring”:“2”,“ScaleUnit”:“001”,“RoleInstance”:“DS2PEPF00000F45”}}
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963002Z X-Ms-Resource-Unit: 1
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963009Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963083Z eb
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963640Z {“error”:{“code”:“Request_BadRequest”,“message”:“Server admin limit exceeded.”,“innerError”:{“date”:“2023-05-05T10:06:24”,“request-id”:“8e624ae8-710f-49e8-a15b-7050cb9b0e42”,“client-request-id”:“8e624ae8-710f-49e8-a15b-7050cb9b0e42”}}}
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963719Z 0
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963726Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9963740Z
2023-05-05T10:06:24.9964019Z ============================= End AzureAD Response ============================: timestamp=2023-05-05T10:06:24.582Z
```

The issue is the same when applying the Terraform plan using a service account in github actions and when applying it from my local machine using my personal account.
I also tried creating the secret using the azure portal and that works without any problems using my personal account.

UPDATE:
To make the issue more clear. Its actually a Graph api issue. I reproduced it with the graph explorer as displayed below. I tried both the beta and 1.0 version with the same result.

[image]

Comment: Hi @MWDoesIT, Can you share your code what you have tried?

Comment: Updated the description to make it more clear that it is a graph api issue.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with the creation of password/client secret to azure ad application.

Code:

```
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name     = "kaexampleapp"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]

}


resource "time_rotating" "example" {
  rotation_days = 7
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "example" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.example.object_id
  rotate_when_changed = {
    rotation = time_rotating.example.id
  }
}
```

Could create the password successfully

[image]

Also with graph api request,it worked.

---

**POST** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/bbcebxx289/microsoft.graph.addPassword`

---

[image]

[image]

> ***Server admin limit exceeded means that you have reached the maximum number of administrative units that are allowed for your organization.
> Azure AD limits the number of administrative to manage the directory
> and its resources.***

**Note:**
A user can have credentials configured for a maximum of 48 apps using password-based single sign-on.

Check out [Service limits and restrictions - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions#:%7E:text=A%20user%20can%20have%20credentials%20configured%20for%20a%20maximum%20of%2048%20apps%20using%20password%2Dbased%20single%20sign%2Don.%20This)